# Python3.5 recursive glob not showing matching files

Tags: python-3.x, glob

With Pyton >= 3.5 `glob` supports recursive searching. I am attempting to do this, but with no success.

Here you can see my directory structure:

```
/Volumes/user/TEST/
└── [NAME]john\ doe,\ peter\ griffin\ -\ sample\ video[29.06.17][1080]{user}
    ├── [NAME]john\ doe,\ perter\ griffin\ -\ sample\ video[29.06.17][1080]{user}.mp4
    ├── [NAME]john\ doe,\ peter\ griffin\ -\ sample\ video[29.06.17][Hi-Res]
    │   ├── 583a6ea574035-img-8399.jpg
    │   ├── 583a6eb9681c0-img-8401.jpg
    │   ├── 583a6eb9e53e1-img-8402.jpg
    │   ├── 583a6ecad078d-img-8404.jpg
    │   ├── 583a6ecd207ed-img-8403.jpg
    │   ├── 583a6edb7348c-img-8405.jpg
    │   ├── 583a6ede1cbfa-img-8406.jpg
    │   ├── 583a6eeb294a9-img-8407.jpg
    │   ├── 583a6eee94a45-img-8408.jpg
    │   ├── 583a6efb2389a-img-8409.jpg
    │   ├── 583a6f01a78ae-img-8410.jpg
    │   ├── 583a6f0daea30-img-8411.jpg
    │   ├── 583a6f1301e3c-img-8412.jpg
    │   ├── 583a6f1ec07d8-img-8413.jpg
    │   ├── 583a6f240d4ce-img-8414.jpg
    │   ├── 583a6f306f517-img-8415.jpg
    │   ├── 583a6f36def7a-img-8416.jpg
    │   ├── 583a6f4280706-img-8417.jpg
    │   ├── 583a6f48b8b11-img-8418.jpg
    │   ├── 583a6f55160cc-img-8419.jpg
    │   ├── 583a6f5b7fb35-img-8420.jpg
    │   ├── 583a6f68aad40-img-8423.jpg
    │   ├── 583a6f6da8c0b-img-8424.jpg
    │   ├── 583a6f7b9e1d6-img-8425.jpg
    │   ├── 583a6f8069e59-img-8426.jpg
    │   ├── 583a6f8e9891e-img-8427.jpg
    │   ├── 583a6f9427910-img-8428.jpg
    │   ├── 583a6fa45e3f4-img-8429.jpg
    │   ├── 583a6fa96b182-img-8430.jpg
    │   ├── 583a6fb935bf2-img-8431.jpg
    │   ├── 583a6fca7a0c9-img-8433.jpg
    │   ├── 583a6fcbab549-img-8434.jpg
    │   ├── 583a6fdcf2812-img-8435.jpg
    │   ├── 583a6fde5ee86-img-8436.jpg
    │   ├── 583a6fee54d9b-img-8437.jpg
    │   ├── 583a6ff0acb76-img-8438.jpg
    │   ├── 583a7000ecd80-img-8439.jpg
    │   ├── 583a70026c325-img-8440.jpg
    │   ├── 583a701319c22-img-8441.jpg
    │   ├── 583a701457221-img-8443.jpg
    │   ├── 583a7027e8531-img-8444.jpg
    │   ├── 583a7029f0e7c-img-8445.jpg
    │   ├── 583a703d6c3c9-img-8446.jpg
    │   ├── 583a703f879f5-img-8447.jpg
    │   ├── 583a7051ae77a-img-8448.jpg
    │   ├── 583a705b588c3-img-8449.jpg
    │   ├── 583a706d40811-img-8450.jpg
    │   ├── 583a7076cb3e9-img-8451.jpg
    │   ├── 583a70894ec35-img-8452.jpg
    │   ├── 583a70964fbcb-img-8453.jpg
    │   ├── cai-8498-pa.jpg
    │   └── cai-8498-pt.jpg
    ├── [NAME]john\ doe,\ peter\ griffin\ -\ sample\ video[29.06.17][Hi-Res].jpg
    └── cover.png
```

So the images are definitely there.
Now here is my method, that for some reason, is not working:

```
def count_images(folder):
    """
    Count the number of images in a folder.
    :param folder: Folder to count the images
    :return: Number of photos
    """
    print(folder)
    files = [file for file in glob.glob(folder + '/**/*.jpg', recursive=True)]
    print(files)
    return len([file for file in glob.glob(folder + '/**/*.jpg', recursive=True)])
```

But it just outputs the following:

```
/Volumes/user/TEST/[NAME]john doe, peter griffin - sample video[29.06.17][1080]{user}/
[]
```

It is becoming extremely frustrating, as I do not see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Try `'/**/**/*.jpg'`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ no difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the problem.
The `glob` module has issues with certain characters in the filename - `[` and `]` in this case. You can use `glob.escape()` to escape these characters in the filename.

So the final function will look like this:

```
def count_images(folder):
    return len([file for file in glob.glob(glob.escape(folder) + '/**/*.jpg', recursive=True)])
```

Comment: Do you happen to have documentation of this? Trying to find if there are other chars `glob` has problems with.

Comment: @DavidoWidre No, but you can check what exactly the `escape()` function does. Most likely a form of character substitution.